# Instruct Angular CLI/Webpack to NOT inline images less than 10Kb in size

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, content-security-policy, inline-images

When building an Angular app with Angular CLI, resources in CSS, e.g. svg images, [less than 10kb in size will be inlined](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#css-resources).

This sounds like a good concept from the performance point of view, however, it **violates** very strict [Content Security Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src) in my app, which I 'm not allowed to change.

My question is as follows: **how can I instruct Angular CLI or Webpack NOT to inline any images?**

Comment: I don't think there is a way to customize webpack plugins with @angular/cli. Not ideal, but you could do ng eject which converts your app to a regular app, so you can modify webpack.config

Comment: @pixelbits yeah, wouldn't want to eject Angular CLI - it worked great so far...

Comment: @AlexanderBurakevych it doesn't eject the `cli`, it ejects `weback.config` which you can then edit.

Comment: Inlining has been completely removed from angular version 7.0 . Do refer issue closure comment on angular github repo. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8945#issuecomment-425509171

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @pixelbits, run `ng eject` in shell to eject the `webpack.config` file. This file will allow you to edit the webpack for the application.

Inside `webpack.config` change `limit` to whatever you require (`0`) ?

```
{
  "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
  "loader": "url-loader",
  "options": {
    "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
    "limit": 10000
  }
}
```

This may mean that you can no longer use `ng serve` as it won't be aware of your new webpack. As a result, navigate to your new webpack directory (same as the `angular-cli.json`) and instead run `webpack-dev-server --port=4200` OR `webpack-dev-server --hot` for `[HMR]`.

Comment: This sounds like the only option at the moment @Zze. Also, unsafe-inline will be needed for style-src and currently unsafe-eval may also be needed for script-src (this can be eliminated by removing reflect polyfills, running in AOT mode, and removing the webpack node global shim from an ejected configuration).

Comment: I have created a PR into Angular CLI github project to add `--inline-asset-max-size` - Maximum size of assets to be inlined https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/8954